# Luis intents with composite terms

Tags: azure-language-understanding, semantic-analysis

I am developping a bot using the LUIS API by Microsoft. This bot must understand queries related to shopping like "I want potatoes".

The only thing my application is struggling with is detecting intents from composite terms:

For the query "I want chopped steak", LUIS will detect chopped as an intent but not "chopped steak". I tried creating a productName phrase list feature and setting different composite terms including "chopped steak" but this doesn't seem to work.

What could I do to achieve that purpose ?

Comment: So you have a 'chopped' intent and a 'chopped steak' intent?

Comment: No I just have a 'chopped' intent and I would like to have a 'chopped steak' intent. I have reproduced the example application shown in this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jWeLajon9M8&t=10m34s) but LUIS would fail to pick "San Diego" as a location, picking only "San", so I'm really confused right now...

Comment: When you want LUIS to pick out words or phrases it's looking for entites, not intents. Do you mean to use the word 'entity' in your comment above in place of 'intent'? In that tutorial 'San Diego' is an entity.

Comment: Yes I'm sorry I meant entity when I was talking about "San Diego" or "chopped steak". I have a "AddToBasket" intent and a "Product" entity. The sentance "Add chopped steak to basket" is correctly identified as a "AddToBasket" intent, but the recognized entity is "chopped" and not "chopped steak" (or "San" instead of "San Diego" for the tutorial example).

Comment: If you're adding "chopped steak" to the phrase list with other product entities that it already recognizes (test this!) then it should be working as it does in the video. If not, can you please post a photo of your "Review Labels" tab showing `all labeled utterances`?

Comment: I actually tried to add several product entities which are already recognized to the phrase-list, and unfortunately it did not seem to help. Here is a picture of my labeled utterances: http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2017/06/1486382772-luis.png you can see that all the intents are in my phrase list. Hoewever if I say "book me a flight to New York", New and York are recognized as two distinct entities, while "New York" is in the phrase list: http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2017/06/1486383360-luis.png It is really weird